# Manage several sub domains with nginx

Tags: nginx, http, regex, regular-expressions

I like to handle different sub domains in my Nginx server, this is my config file (partially)

```
server {
    listen                              80 default_server;
    listen                              443 default_server ssl;

    include                             ssl/mysite.conf;

    server_name                         default_server;
    rewrite                             ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com$1 permanent;
```

As you can see all the requests to **sub-domain.mysite.com/query** are *redirected* to **mysite.com/query** always in **https**. I will like to execute that rewrite only if the sub-domain is different from *string1* and *string2*. So:

```
string1.mysite.com/query     --->   https://string1.mysite.com/query
foo.mysite.com/query         --->   https://mysite.com/query
```

Comment: Why don't you use 2 server blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify different server blocks to different hostnames like AD7six suggested.

In your case, I would write 2 server blocks, one for string1.mysite.com and string2.mysite.com and another without the server_name filter to match all other requests.

Something like this:

```
server {
    listen                              80 default_server;
    listen                              443 default_server ssl;

    include                             ssl/mysite.conf;

    rewrite                             ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com$1 permanent;
    ...
}

server {
    listen                              80;
    listen                              443 ssl;

    include                             ssl/mysite.conf;

    server_name                         string1.mysite.com string2.mysite.com;
    ...
}
```

The server_name directive documentation is very good and can help you with this kind of problem.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html